# Firebase: Send OTP but disable sign in using phone number

Tags: javascript, firebase, one-time-password

I am working on a simple registration. I planned to use email to create an account, the problem is upon submission of form, the phone number also signed in as new user.

How can I prevent that from happening? What I only need to use is the send otp feature.

```
      sendOTP() {
        var self = this
        const phoneNumber = '+' + this.phone;
        const appVerifier = window.recaptchaVerifier;
        firebase.auth().signInWithPhoneNumber(phoneNumber, appVerifier)
          .then((confirmationResult) => {
            window.confirmationResult = confirmationResult;
            self.otpSent = true
          }).catch((error) => {
            self.errorMsg = error.code + ': ' + error.message;
          });
      },
      register() {
        var self = this
        const code = this.otp;
        window.confirmationResult.confirm(code).then((result) => {
          console.log(result)
          firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(this.email, this.password)
            .then((userCredential) => {
              firebase.database().ref('users').set({
                email: this.email,
                name: this.name,
                password: this.password,
                phone: this.phone,
                userCredential: userCredential
              }, (error) => {
                if (error) {
                  // The write failed...
                  self.errorMsg = error.message
                } else {
                  self.$router.push('/dashboard')

                }
              });
            })
            .catch((error) => {
              self.errorMsg = error.message
            });

        }).catch((error) => {
          self.errorMsg = error.message;
        });
      }
```

Comment: Can you post the rest of your code? The issue is not clear atm

Answer (score 1):

glad to see you are trying to utilize the firebase's mobile verifications but see the problem is you are trying to use the SDK, which has been programmed by the people at Firebase to perform things in a certain way.

Below example takes an assumption that you have a Firebase Firestore DB at the backend, but this can even work with RealTime DB too.

> If you can write a cloud function backend and maintain say a profile of user in a /userDetails collection where the individual document records are stored with the User UID of your Firebase Authentication, there you can store a phone number and its boolean status as phoneVerified: true or false.

> Hence the collection in the Firestore would look like /userDetails/UserUID/ with fields phoneNumber as Number and phoneVerified:true or false

Do it at the backend by triggering an API call to the cloudfunction.

[Then you can refer to this link too](https://medium.com/google-developer-experts/verifying-phone-numbers-with-firebase-phone-authentication-on-your-backend-for-free-7a9bef326d02)
Best Regards !!

:-)